# How to check url whether url is valid in lua?

Tags: url, lua, lua-patterns

I want to check if url is valid, what is the correct regexp to do that in lua?
I tried regexp like this

```
string.match('https://stackoverflow.com/', '[a-z]*:\/\/[^ >,;]*')
```

but getting error

```
invalid escape sequence near ''[a-z]*:\/'
```

Update:

```
string.match('https://stackoverflow.com/', '[a-z]*://[^ >,;]*')
```

is correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is fairly clear: `\/` is an invalid escape. You don't need to escape `/`, as it's not a special character in Lua patterns ([check the list of "magic" characters](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)) and removing the escape should work: `string.match('https://stackoverflow.com/', '[a-z]*://[^ >,;]*')`.